# Uncaught ReferenceError: getMoreSongs(function) is not defined onclick

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

This data gets from API.
I want to create pagination.
if the next button clicked, then the next page will show.

```js
function buttons(data){
if (data.prev || data.next) {
    more.innerHTML = `
            ${
              data.prev
                ? `
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getMoreSongs('${data.prev}')">Prev</button>
            `
                : ""
            }

            ${
              data.next
                ? `
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getMoreSongs('${data.next}')">Next</button>
            `
                : ""
            }
        `;
  } else {
    more.innerHTML = "";
  }
  }
  
  //pagiantion
function getMoreSongs(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      showData(data);
    });
}
```

when i click on Next Button then browser console show this massage

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getMoreSongs is not defined
> onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?:1
> index.html:1:1

what's wrong here?

Comment: `getMoreSongs` needs to be defined in the global scope, you've probably defined it inside a function.

Comment: A quick fix will be `window.getMoreSongs = getMoreSongs` but a better fix is to define the function in the global scope.

Comment: also `getMoreSongs('${data.prev}')` is not going to do what you expect ... the url will be exactly the string `${data.prev}` - which isn't a url at all

Comment: @Titus thank u so much, bro. now it's work.

Comment: Edit your post to reflect  the answer, close the question, and it would be nice to give Titus a vote up